# Document representation with pre-trained Word Vectors for Author Classification/Regression (GP)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, text-classification, word-embedding

I am trying to replicate (https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.05513) to do a Big 5 author classification on Facebook data (posts and Big 5 profiles are given).

After removing the stop words, I embed each word in the file with their pre-trained GloVe word vectors. However, computing the average or coordinate-wise min/max word vector for each user and using those as input for a Gaussian Process/SVM gives me terrible results. Now I wonder what the paper means by:

> Our method combines Word Embedding with Gaussian
>   Processes. We extract the words from the users’ tweets and
>   average their Word Embedding representation into a single
>   vector. The Gaussian Processes model then takes these
>   vectors as an input for training and testing.

What else can I "average" the vectors to get decent results and do they use some specific Gaussian Process?